# Is it possible to create a RHEL 6 repo on a RHEL 7 server

Tags: redhat, rhel6, rhel7, repository

I am trying to create a RHEL 6 repository, but since I have a RHEL 7 repository, I was thinking if it is possible to create that repo on the same server.

I already have a valid and currently registered subscription on the RHEL 7 server, but when y run `# subscription-manager repos --list` I only see RHEL 7 repos on the list and whey I try adding `rhel-6-server-rpms` repo (which appears to be part of the content I have available in my subscription) I get:

## subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-6-server-rpms

Error: 'rhel-6-server-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.

Any ideas of what is happening or how can I enable that repo?

Comment: You can use Satellite for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The repos for RHEL 6 are not available for RHEL 7 because there would be a carnival of package conflicts, dependency hells on earth, and utter chaos.

Can you imagine `yum` trying to install RHEL 6 packages or just packages that aren't compatible with what's available in RHEL 7 because the former is deprecated?

The `subscription manager` doesn't allow what you're trying to do for this very reason.

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense. I just thought there was a way to define those not to be actually used. Thanks for the answer, Nasir!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but since I just had to finish doing this, yes it's possible. You require a valid subscription for RHEL 6 and 7.

Subscribe both hosts using `subscription-manager register;subscription-manager attach --auto` then run `yum clean all`.

Copy the entitlement keys from /etc/pki/entitlement on the RHEL 6 host to the same folder on the RHEL 7 host.

Copy the redhat.repo file from /etc/yum.repos.d/ on the RHEL 6 host into the same folder on the RHEL 7 host. **NOTE:** Name this file something else, like rhel-6.repo, because the redhat.repo is overwritten when you run a `yum clean all`.

Now run a `yum clean all` and ensure none of the keys or repo files were removed.

If everything is still intact, you're ready to to create the local repo.
Install/Start httpd.
Create a directory `mkdir /var/www/html/rhel6/`.
Run `reposync --gpgcheck -l --repoid=rhel-6-workstation-rpms --download_path=/var/www/html/rhel6/ --downloadcomps --download-metadata --newest-only`
Once the download is complete, create the repo with: `createrepo -v /var/www/html/rhel6/rhel-6-workstation-rpms/ -g comps.xml`

Now any other RHEL 6 hosts can point to `http://server-ip/rhel6/rhel-6-workstation-rpms/`
I would suggest setting up HTTPS, but this will get you going. You can also repeat these steps for any other RHEL 6 repos like optional or extras if you wish. This is really useful when you want to host an internal repo, cutting down external bandwidth.